# TimescaleDB for unsorted data series

Tags: timescaledb

TimescaleDB fits very well for data series.

In my case, I'm working with data series but my data arrives not sorted.

Will TimescaleDB work in the same way compared with data coming sorted ?

Comment: I can give you a more detailed answer, but one question first: does your data come unsorted but still moves forward in time in a monotonous fashion e.g. you are inserting data in a random order at the present time for the last 2-3 days, insert/update data for the last week sometimes, and rarely insert data for periods before that?

Comment: Hi @BlagojAtanasovski . I'm loading data (facts) in a fact table (DW). Our date has two column dates (fact_date and last_update_date). We use the last_update_date to get all the inserted/updated facts that happened TODAY()-1. But the column fact_date is the one used as key/index. So every day we might have hundreds of facts from different days (weeks, months, years) in that batch. Do I answered your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TimescaleDB is a good solution for your problem. It does not put a constraint on data coming in a sorted fashion. Timescale partitions your data on a dimension of your choice, time being the most often example of a monotonous dimension (but any integer type can be used to partition the data). You specify a partition size (chunk size) and TimescaleDB creates new partitions automatically for each interval. As long as your data comes in the interval range of a few chunks, then the database can work with those chunks in memory, speeding up ingestion rates. It doesn't matter if the data comes in absolutely sorted. Because TimescaleDB is built on PostgreSQL it does not have an append-only storage model making it possible to even modify old data, or even back-fill without sacrificing performance.

Another benefits of using TimescaleDB:

- Native compression, can reduce storage requirements up to 20x or 30x (and more depending on your data layout)
- Data Tiering: attach tablespaces on slower storage, and automatically move old chunks to the slower storage
- Continuous Aggreages: define materialized views that refresh automatically
- Optimizations that efficiently prune out chunks that don't need to be scanned based on your query predicates, based on the partitioning you choose

Comment: But be careful with compression: AFAIK you can currently not insert data into compressed chunks and when compression is on, you cannot (easily) alter the table (e.g. add a column, ..)

Comment: Yes, compressed chunks can not be modified, you will have to manually decompress them before inserting/updating into them. But you can specify a compression policy that will run compression only on data that is older than some interval https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#add_compress_chunks_policy